# Use Django models.FileField to read file from memory and discard it before it is written to the directory

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

How can I read a file using Django's `models.FileField`, handle the data in memory, and then discard it before django tries to save/write it to my directory. I want to discard the file, but still save the other fields for the model. I now that I can use forms and views to handle files, but I want to do it through the admin interface without a lot of extra logic

```
class DataField(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    title = models.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataField, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        some_background_task(self.file)
        # skip saving the file and avoid writing to directory, but save other fields
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class DataField(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        some_background_task(self.file)
        self.file = None

        super(DataField, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```